# Why is Hogwarts Library so badly organized?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

In *Harry Potter and The Philosophers Stone*, Harry, Ron and Hermione have serious trouble finding some information about Nicolas Flamel in the Library:

> They had indeed been searching books for Flamel's name ever since Hagrid had let it slip, because how else were they going to find out what Snape was trying to steal? The trouble was, it was very hard to know where to begin, not knowing what Flamel might have done to get himself into a book. He wasn't in Great Wizards of the Twentieth Century, or Notable Magical Names of Our Time; he was missing, too, from Important Modern Magical Discoveries, and A Study of Recent Developments in Wizardry. And then, of course, there was the sheer size of the library; tens of thousands of books; thousands of shelves; hundreds of narrow rows.

Looks like they were just picking books and hoping to find something in them.

However, libraries have various techniques to solve this problem. For example library catalogs ([Library Catalogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_catalog)) or classification systems ([Library Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_classification)). These systems have existed since the 18th century.

The only "sort of" catalog in there is Madam Pince but in general she cares more about keeping silence than helping the students.

So why are there no index cards or catalogs in Hogwarts Library?

Since there was a lots of discussion on the topic - here a short summary:

- Looks like I overestimated the usefulness of library indexes - several people shared their own experience - if you don't have much information to start with, it is still a long search.
- JKR make Madam Pince's character unpleasant and unhelpful for plot purposes. This of course can not be considered a "plot hole" since unpleasant and unhelpful librarians do exist in the real world too (I have met some :) ).
- It is plausible to assume that actually Hogwarts library had more or less a decent index but due to the limited information that was available at the start and the unhelpful librarian, the Trio had trouble finding anything.

Comment: Maybe the problem was even if there was a catalog they didnt know where to look in it. they had no idea what was the topic(s) of the books NF appeared in. If he wasn't an author, or his name hasn't appeared in the title etc. then even a catalog wouldn't help. And it could be wizards use the accio spell to find books so they don't need catalogues. I guess they could've asked madam p, but they probably wanted to keep their investigation a secret.

Comment: @R.Skeeter `And it could be wizards use the *accio* spell to find books(..)`. Nice solution, except you cant yell *accio* in the library... actually, can you use *accio* without yelling *accio*? Citation needed!

Comment: @xDaizu both [accio](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Charm) and SELECT are magic words that can be used non-verbally :)

Comment: @R.Skeeter hahaha, not to question you, but can you provide an example of either and/or both? :P

Comment: @xDaizu just open the link i provided in the comment above,  there are examples of non-verbal uses for summining spells from canon

Comment: In a libary, casting 'accio book' maybe a very very bad idea. I leave the rest to the imagination.

Comment: @djsmiley2k the person who casts 'accio book' without specifying which one in a lib deserves his fate.

Comment: I think it is the monkey librarian who constantly puts books out of their place... oh, wait...

Comment: If Harry and Hermione think their library is disorganized, they really should talk with Kvothe...

Comment: That's pretty easy to answer. It's because they don't have an Orangutan for a librarian (who would also keep the wizards in their place).

Comment: Maybe because it's a wizard school and wizards have something against boring muggle systems like library index cards.

Comment: Also, apparently the wizarding world has not developed the concept of an encyclopedia.

Comment: It also reminded me of "Name of the Rose" by Umberto Eco, where the very index of books in the library was kept secret.

Comment: @vap78 as someone who spent many many years doing extensive library research, I can tell you that you _dramatically_ overestimate how useful (pre-computing) library cataloging systems are when you know very little about your chosen topic to begin with.

Comment: @KutuluMike even if you have a name?

Comment: sure. the library catalog doesn't track every word in every book; it tracks categories, topics, titles, authors, etc. If all you have is "I need to know stuff about this guy", unless that guy happens to have his own biography written about him, you're going to spend a lot of time pulling books and flipping through their indices.

Comment: It's kind of surprising they didn't have a subscription to the annual "Who's Who in the Wizarding World".  But it has often occurred to me that Hogwarts isn't actually organized to be _effective_ at teaching wizards.  The school behaves, in some ways, more like the bar association - a trade group trying to keep people out.  Snape's teaching methods leave a _lot_ to be desired, useless electives like Divination with equally useless teachers, and let's not even get started about Binns.

Comment: I've always found this part weird. Nicolas Flamel is not unheard of in the muggles world, why couldn't Hermione (raised in the muggles world) look it up in Encarta (it was a bit too early for wikipedia, sadly) or in an encyclopedia with alphabetic index? At least it would have given them clues guiding further investigation in the magical knowledge base...

Comment: Why ON EARTH don't they have a computerised lookup system? It's a joke.

Comment: Perhaps we need to borrow from some other writer for an answer - Terry Pratchett. And L-Space. http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/L-space Oook?

Comment: They were First years looking in the Restricted Section without permission. They could not ask Pince because her answer would have been to "get out!".  So I am not sure that the OP is fair in assuming the library was disorganised. It was protected.

Comment: @niico Computers (and other electronics) don't work in and around Hogwarts, but you'd think by now someone would have developed specialized spells or some other magical system to find relevant books. Perhaps Madam Pince knows how to use such a system, but they just never ask her for help for one reason or another.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

There's no evidence that the library **was** badly organised. In every instance when students need information on a specific, *known* subject, they're able to easily find the book(s) they need on that topic.

The issue in *Philosopher's Stone* is that the problem they're trying to solve isn't one that any system of classifying or organising books would assist in solving. Nicolas Flamel apparently wasn't an author or the specific subject of a book so his name wouldn't appear in a catalog. They would need the Hogwarts library to have details of everything mentioned in the *contents* of a book, in addition to the author and title, which is simply not feasible given the "tens of thousands of books" the library contains.

The nature of the problem is even explicitly stated in the passage you quoted:

> The trouble was, it was very hard to know where to begin, not knowing what Flamel might have done to get himself into a book.

The problem is made worse by their (logical, but ultimately incorrect) assumption that he must have been famous for something that occurred in the last century, and limited their search accordingly. They didn't consider the possibility of an (almost) immortal wizard who may be famous for something that happened well outside the expected lifespan of a normal witch or wizard.

Comment: Indexes are not limited to authors and titles. Usually if a certain name is mentioned in a book then the index will show it. Also Flamel is famous enough to be on a chocolate frog card.

Comment: @vap78 It has, admittedly, been many years since I stepped foot inside a library, but I don't recall them ever having a listing of every single thing mentioned inside every single book they have, and which books they're mentioned in. Possibly in an electronic system that would be possible, but when that information is taking up physical space and has to be updated by hand, it's simply not feasible.

Comment: "if a certain name is mentioned in a book then the index will show it". Yes, but until you know which book he might be mentioned in you can't check the index of it. The problem is guessing which book might mention him, not checking if it does.

Comment: With regards to the chocolate frog card: yes, but so what? Being famous doesn't mean he's written any books, or that any books have been written specifically about him, that the Hogwarts library includes. He may have written the magic equivalent of scientific research papers, but it appears the library doesn't include those (because they're probably too advanced or just totally irrelevant for the majority of students). It's entirely possible that, had the Trio looked in "Notable Wizards of the Last Millennia" (to my knowledge, not a real book) they would have found him with ease.

Comment: @DJClayworth it is not the index of the book but the index of the library. I.e. if George Washington is mentioned in "History of the US Revolution" then in the INDEX entry of George Washington you will see a reference to the book with information about the section, shelf etc.

Comment: `The issue in Philosopher's Stone is that the problem they're trying to solve isn't one that any system of classifying or organising books would assist in solving.` Wow wow WOOOOW, I'm gonna put up a [citation needed] for that *"not **any** system"* :P. Computers can brute force, cross-reference and algorithm-pass every book in existence if it's digitalized. That's why they need to adopt computers. **ASAP.** Just *google book* it, goddammit!

Comment: By this logic, magic (from which, after all, no sufficiently advanced technology is distinguishable) should be able to take a search phrase, and *magically* search all of the books to find the reference. The Hogwarts equivalent of Google Books.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist This sounds like the kind of problem magic could solve.

Comment: @vap78 Dont forget in philosophers stone, they were looking in the completely wrong books anyway, Hermione says something about focusing on current wizards, because they believed him a contemporary of Dumbledore, and the reason they missed him is hes some 600 years old.

So even if the indexes of the books had his name in them, the fact that they were looking in books 500 years off to begin with would still have blocked them from finding the answer till they broadened their timeline.

Comment: @BauceLawyerson It's definitely possible that "*Accio books about Nicolas Flamel*" would have worked - since apparently "*Accio books about Horcruxes*" works - had they been facing this particular problem a few years later.

Comment: "‘And no wonder we couldn’t find Flamel in that Study of Recent

Developments in Wizardry,’ said Ron. ‘He’s not exactly recent if he’s

six hundred and sixty-five, is he?’"

Comment: @xDaizu, I'm not sure how efficient Google Search was in the 90s, though.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Given Google Search was launched in 1997, I'll go ahead and say "not very efficient" :P

Comment: @Himarm looking in the wrong place is an indication for a problem. A well-organized library will allow you to find the relevant books for a certain name or topic. Think of it as a primitive version of Google with lots of manual work but it is still much more efficient compared to reading the books one by one.

Comment: I'm torn on this. On one hand, as someone who has searched libraries using a card index on numerous occasions to find very specific books, I have to assert that efficient searching did exist pre-Google. On the other hand, that experience taught me that some things are way easier to find than others, and often you progress by finding synonyms and related topics to help narrow the field or find what you're after by other routes, and the trio were unable to do this - until Harry found the mention of the Philosopher's Stone, at which point Hermione found him easily, which fits with my experiences.

Comment: I remember the good ol' fasion card catalog.  Sure the computerized card catalogs are better these days, but for hundreds - thousands of years people got by with just the card catalog. And yes you could find some horribly obscure references using it. It just took a bit of skill.

Comment: @Anthony Grist, though in that particular instance "Accio" was a spell they wouldn't learn for another three years, so they'd need to learn the spell before they could use it to find anything.

Comment: @coteyr Fortunately for suspension of disbelief, the skill pool available tops out at the maximum research skills of a very bright 10 year old girl with no background in wizardry, a wizarding native with a mediocre academic record and Harry, who combines the worst of both worlds, being both academically average, and a non-wizarding native.

Comment: Harry and co were also, what, 12/13 in the first book? Their researching skills are not going to be on the same level as an adult's. The "pick books at random" sounds quite like a Ron-strategy. Perhaps Hermione probably would have been better than the others, but I doubt she had much experience in magical libraries, only muggle ones. Which leads us to the next question - why not just *ask an adult* for help?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez `I'm not sure how efficient Google Search was in the 90s, though.` Fair point, though I'd argue that *efficient* is not as important compared with *effective*. As long as it is effective, you could leave the search computing overnight and check the results in the morning :)

Comment: I would like to point in quite a heavy manner that all they new was Nicholas Flamel's name.If there was an index,then that would mean he was a major role in that book's content or he authored it.Let's assume that Flamel neither wrote a book nor had any written about him within Howarts.He might be a minor footnote as one of the several people to own the Philosopher's Stone over thousands of years. Depending on the depth of the history,Flamel might only have a paragraph written about him. He's famous to *us* but what if the fame goes to some Greek such as Euclid or Plato for living 3000 years?

Comment: So what I've learned from this comment section, is that _Accio_ is like a physical google search. You specify the query in your mind, and the magic somehow magically figures out what items match it.

Comment: @karhell: when it was launched it was so good it made the competition obsolete immediately, it was indistinguishable from magic. So magic would have worked.

Comment: Guys, spells have to be developed, just like software needs to be developed. I know most people don't think about it, but a search engine is massively complicated, not something that just comes with having technology at all. In the same way a search engine spell wouldn't come with having magic. I'd assume developing a "search for a name in a book collection" spell would take lots of research as well.

Answer (score 45):

For an out-of-universe answer, J.K. Rowling [has said this](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0802-radiocityreading2.html) about the role of Madam Pince, the librarian:

> I thought you were going to attack me for Madam Pince and I would like to apologize for you and any other librarians (crowd laughs) present here today and my get-out clause is always if they’d had a pleasant, helpful librarian, half my plots would be gone. ’Cause the answer invariably is in a book but Hermione has to go and find it. If they’d had a good librarian, that would have been that problem solved. So, sorry.

The same reasoning applies to the library itself and any tools such as catalogues: if all information was magically easy to find, it would damage the plots.

Comment: You say `if all information was magically easy to find, it would damage the plots` but that's very subjective. It might as well improve it if the plot doesn't drag where it shouldn't and finds better (more interesting) places to create tension and struggle.

Comment: @xDaizu: I was paraphrasing JKR (“half my plots would be gone”).

Comment: I know, wasn't trying to argue, but the phrasing made it sound like generic advice. Something on the lines of "The story tha author has planned wouldn't work", or "It would damage the plot it in the eyes of the author" would make clear that the damage to the story is not objective, it is just this author's opinion. My point is "make information easy to obtain" is not something that is generally considered *"bad practice"* in storytelling, like "having too many pointless characters and introducing them very quickly" [citation needed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0803096/) ^^

Answer (score 10):

**Everything** in the wizarding world is poorly organized. That's part of its charm. Why should the library be different?

Comment: Although I agree, your answer could use some support. As it is, it's not very helpful; but it should be relatively easy to find necessary arguments.

Comment: Voldemort, on the other side, is very efficient and well-organized :)

Comment: I think, given a present day setting, a nerd would figure out a google-spell to acquire information.

Comment: @vap78 Not convinced that's supported by the text. His plans do tend to involve an awful lot of theatrics that get him into trouble.

Comment: @deworde consider how efficiently were the rounding up the muggle-borns

Comment: @vap78 Moral of the story, then, is that efficiency and organization are a sign of deep-seated evil.

Answer (score 8):

Why would you expect an effecitve organisational structure?

The wizarding world is less advanced (in science, maths, economics and logic) then the 18th century muggle world.

This is a society that skipped the enlightenment, the renaissance, and the industrial revolution.

It is also a much smaller world than ours. Estimates of the total wizarding population worldwide is [50,000 people](https://www.quora.com/How-big-is-the-wizarding-world-in-terms-of-population-in-Harry-Potter-series). There are less books, less authors and less librarians. Perhaps the Librarian would be more helpful if a teacher had come to her with the same request.

See the [organisational system of pre-enlightenment societies.](http://eduscapes.com/history/ancient/200bce.htm)

Comment: If the demographics of wizards are similar to those of muggles (in particular, Flamel needs to be an exception), it would mean that the total number of wizards who ever lived is less than 1 million. It is estimated that the total number of books ever written in the muggles world is about 130 million, or 1.3 per thousand humans. The Hogwarts library alone contains at the very least 100,000 books, I guess wizards are really prolific writers.

Answer (score 0):

## The library may *not* be badly organized.

Harry, Ron, and Hermione being unable to find Nicolas Flamel without asking the librarian or knowing anything more than his name does not prove that the Hogwarts library is badly organized.

## The trio did not ask the librarian to help.

Harry, Ron, and Hermione were attempting to find out who Flamel was without many people knowing they were looking, particularly wanting Snape not to know. They suspected she would know which books they could find Flamel in, though.

> “Wishing he’d been a bit quicker at thinking up some story, Harry left the library. He, Ron and Hermione had already agreed they’d better not ask Madam Pince where they could find Flamel. They were sure she’d be able to tell them, but they couldn’t risk Snape hearing what they were up to.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 12 (The Mirror of Erised)*</sup></sub>

Because of their need for secrecy, they did not actually ask for any help searching the library.

## They also had very little information.

Additionally, since Harry, Ron, and Hermione all did not know who Nicolas Flamel was or what category of book to look in, they did not know where to look for him. Hermione at least had a plan, Ron was just pulling random books off of the shelves.

> “Hermione took out a list of subjects and titles she had decided to search while Ron strode off down a row of books and started pulling them off the shelves at random. Harry wandered over to the Restricted Section. He had been wondering for a while if Flamel wasn’t somewhere in there. Unfortunately, you needed a specially signed note from one of the teachers to look in any of the restricted books and he knew he’d never get one.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 12 (The Mirror of Erised)*</sup></sub>

With so little information, it would be extremely difficult to find information in any library.

Answer (score -3):

The books move of their own accord, and they change with use cases and with the passage of time.  All the above actually happen in the Potter series.  Madame Pince's job is not easy!

It's MAGIC, remember?  Even the stairways aren't statically bound.

Comment: I don't ever remember reading anything about the books moving around. Got any relevant quotes?

Comment: @Jayraj  -  they fly around in the movies.